# Why "BlockRead" can use a buffer whose size is smaller than the size of the data being read

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have a program:

```
program OverflowTest;
var
    src: file;
    dest: file;
    res: longint;
    buf: byte;
begin
    assign(src, '48_bytes_file.txt');
    assign(dest, 'copy_of_48_bytes_file.txt');
    reset(src, 2);
    rewrite(dest, 2);
    BlockRead(src, buf, 24, res);   
    BlockWrite(dest, buf, 24, res);
    close(src);
    close(dest);
end.
```

Here I am reading 48 bytes of data into the variable `buf`, which can only contain one byte (because it is of type `byte`). And it works. The data is successfully copied to the second file without data loss.

Why can I write 48 bytes of data to a 1 byte variable? Why there are no errors like "memory overflow", "invalid buffer size"?

Comment: Did you read the docs? Which setting do you need to set in order to get an `EInOutError`?

Comment: There are no exceptions if the program works fine. But I still tried to catch this error using try-except construction and did not catch anything. And the main question is how can I write 48 bytes of data to a 1-byte variable.

Comment: Ofcourse you can't write more than 1 byte data to a 1 byte variable. Your program reserves much more global memory than what you specify for variables. Without error detection your program will happily use memory beyond that reserved for `buf`. To verify, declare a few `byte` variables after `buf` and check what they contain after `BlockRead()`, and compare with what your '48_bytes...' file contains.